# Getting advertisingId before WebView loads

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView, nothing special just

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("APP-X-OS", "Android");
headers.put("APP-X-VERSION", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
headers.put("APP-X-DEVICE-ID", Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

webView.loadUrl(
        getString(R.string.app_host_name),
        headers
);
```

and i am editing user agent like this

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUserAgentString(
        String.format(
                "%s/%s %s EmbeddedBrowser DeviceUID: %s",
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,
                webSettings.getUserAgentString(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID // @TODO AdvertisingID
        )
);
```

problem is, my website is using [Gemius](https://www.gemius.com/homepage.html) and until december 21, i need to update my user agent, just to change *Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID* to [AdvertisingIdClient ID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.html) but problem is

> This method cannot be called in the main thread as it may block leading to ANRs. An IllegalStateException will be thrown if this is called on the main thread.

So i need to retrieve Advertising ID in AsyncTask, and i am doing that like this

```
private class getAdvertisingUid extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        AdvertisingIdClient.Info advertising = null;

        try {
            advertising = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(
                    getApplicationContext()
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String uid = null;

        try {
            uid = advertising.getId();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return uid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String uid) {
        advertisingUid = uid;
    }
}
```

but because task is async, i am getting advertising id already AFTER loading WebView and changing UserAgent, so i can't use this id in my user agent, but maybe there is still possibility i don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved whole

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUserAgentString(
        String.format(
                "%s/%s %s EmbeddedBrowser DeviceUID: %s",
                getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name),
                BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,
                webSettings.getUserAgentString(),
                uid != null ? uid : Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
        )
);
```

to *onPostExecute* method, and everything works fine! Also it is possible to use something like this if you are dependent on the result

```
asyncTask.execute().get();
```